# How do I fix this issue?

Tags: python, string

Hello I'm new to python and I was trying to print something (here's the code)

```
import random

print ("Welcome To Pasword Generator")

adjective = ['fluffy', 'cute', 'hangry', 'weird', 'wet', 'you think of some']

noun = ['costco', 'park', 'MT Creek', 'Stop N Shop', 'Target', 'Ball', 'John', 'Lepartymos']

adjective = random.choice(adjective)

noun = random.choice(noun)

number = random.randrange(0, 99999999)

special_char = random.choice

password = adjective + noun + str(number) + special_char
print(password)
```

and it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 19, in <module>
    password = adjective + noun + str(number) + special_char
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "method") to str
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Compare the `special_char = random.choice` line against the previous use of `random.choice` a few lines above.

Answer (score 2):

So basically you’re setting special_char = random.choice
‘. ‘operator is used for invoking method . you cannot concatenate method with number or str . dot operator is used as connection between the attributes .

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment `special_char = random.choice` is assigning the *method* `random.choice` to that variable on the left (methods are first class objects in Python). That's because it's not followed by the parameter set, as in `random.choice(something)`.

What you want to assign is the *result* of a function, most likely akin to:

```py
special_char = random.choice(['!', '@', ':']) # plus more characters.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't concatenate (special_char) which is a method (random.choice) + strings (str). You need to pass in list to special_char = random.choice(list) to choose from.